# Is there a standard data science workflow/decision tree?

Tags: predictive-modeling, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I'm looking for some kind of reference that essentially shows an example of an entire data analysis workflow beginning with feature engineering, and ending with analyzing the results.

I know the typical steps are something like this:

1. Feature engineering
2. Feature selection
3. Choosing the model
4. Training the model
5. Using the model for inference
6. Assessing the performance of the model. Maybe do some EDA, etc...

I feel like I've read bits and pieces about each of these, but would like a more consolidated reference that talks about each in detail.

Answer (score 2):

David Robinson uploaded dozens of such analyses to youtube, as recordings of his screen while doing the analysis. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ub92c-5xFQ&list=PL19ev-r1GBwkuyiwnxoHTRC8TTqP8OEi8) is the link to the playlist.

These come from "Tidy Tuesday" (see the [github repo](https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday)), a weekly social data project that every week posted a real-world dataset for people to play with it. David Robinson uploaded his analyses using R to youtube.

Other people also posted Tidy Tuesday screencasts in Python ([playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiQdjX20rXMHc43KqsdIowHI3ouFnP_Sf)), if you prefer.